# Definition of a metonymy

Tags: metonyms

Metonymy is often used in every day speech.
One of the examples of metonymy is to refer to the content by the container (*ex: I drank a glass*).
I was wondering if using the container to refer to the set that comprises the container and the content is considered a metonymy?
If not is there a word for it?

Comment: Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: Do you have in mind a usage such as in the following sentences: "They ordered a few glasses in the evening; the glasses brought to them finally weren't cool enough and they complained." ? The question would then be "What does "glass" refer to in this case?". Right?

Comment: Yes. I could also give another example. I could say to someone give me the folder on the table. In this case the term folder refers to the folder and its content as well.